# Using whereRaw clause in knex for postgres client

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

The following pagination query works fine if I want to fetch all the columns from a table given the following arguments

```
getOrdersPagination(limit, after) {

    let where = '';
    if (after > 0) {
        where = `id < ${after}`;
    }

    return knex
        .select(
            'id',
            'patient_id AS patientId',
            'pharmacy_id AS pharmacyId',
            'customer_id AS customerId',
            'department_id AS departmentId',
            'user_id AS userId',
            'status',
            'info',
            'created_at AS createdAt'
        )
        .from('order')
        .whereRaw(where)
        .orderBy('id', 'desc')
        .limit(limit);
}
```

However, if I am passing another argument (in this case `status`) to further filter out the rows returned, I am getting exactly the same output as the aforementioned query. The `status` field (integer) does not have any affect on my `getOrdersByStatusPagination` query.

```
getOrdersByStatusPagination(limit, after, status) {

    let where = '';
    if (after > 0) {
        where = `id < ${after} AND status = ${status}`;
    }

    return knex
        .select(
            'id',
            'patient_id AS patientId',
            'pharmacy_id AS pharmacyId',
            'customer_id AS customerId',
            'department_id AS departmentId',
            'user_id AS userId',
            'status',
            'info',
            'created_at AS createdAt'
        )
        .from('order')
        .whereRaw(where)
        .orderBy('id', 'desc')
        .limit(limit);
}
```

I wonder if I am using the `whereRaw` clause correctly to include multiple where statements using `AND` operator.

http://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereRaw

I can also include a sample JSON output of the query, but I am not sure if that is of any help since it is just fetching all the data from the mentioned columns.

Comment: I hope you don't set `after` and `status` directly from user input without validation e.g. http query parameters. If they are set like that there is SQL injection hole. 

You should pretty much always use parameter bindings also when using `whereRaw` like this: `.whereRaw('id < ? AND status = ?', [after, status])`

Comment: None of the parameter is passed by an user input. It is defined in my graphql queries business logic. However, thanks for reminding me about parameter bindings.

Comment: ${after} - string interpolation is a sql injection risk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I figure out is to use another `where` clause in the query along with `whereRaw`. But I would still like to hear if someone knows how can I use the `status` arg in `whereRaw` option

Solution with another `where` clause

```
getOrdersByStatusPagination(limit, after, status) {

    let where = '';
    if (after > 0) {
        where = `id < ${after}`;
    }

    return knex
        .select(
            'id',
            'patient_id AS patientId',
            'pharmacy_id AS pharmacyId',
            'customer_id AS customerId',
            'department_id AS departmentId',
            'user_id AS userId',
            'status',
            'info',
            'created_at AS createdAt'
        )
        .from('order')
        .whereRaw(where)
        .where('status', '=', status)
        .orderBy('id', 'desc')
        .limit(limit);
}
```

Comment: how do you parameterize the values in the whereRaw clause? I am trying to pass something like whereRaw(‘? = ANY(tags) OR 'firsttag' = ANY(tags) OR 'second'’, tagArray) but his errors out. I have to pass whereRaw(‘? = ANY(tags) OR 'firsttag' = ANY(tags) OR 'second'’, ['val1', 'val2'])

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the `knex` way of solving your problem

The basic idea is. You create an instance of `knex` builder and conditionally add clauses to it.

```
getOrdersByStatusPagination (limit, after, status) {
    const builder = knex
        .select(
            'id',
            'patient_id AS patientId',
            'pharmacy_id AS pharmacyId',
            'customer_id AS customerId',
            'department_id AS departmentId',
            'user_id AS userId',
            'status',
            'info',
            'created_at AS createdAt'
        )
        .from('order')
        .whereRaw(where)
        .where('status', status) // No need for '=' argument. Knex inserts it by default
        .orderBy('id', 'desc')
        .limit(limit);

    if (after > 0) {
        builder.where('id', '<', after) // No need for .whereRaw method. You can use the same as for statuses' '='
        // or builder.whereRaw(`id < ${after}`)
    }
    return builder
}
```

Comment: ${after} - string interpolation is a sql injection risk